# Alter OG Menu Structure

Tags: organic-groups, navigation

I need to alter the structure of the OG Menu to build it into a Mega Menu. I'm using the OG Menu: Single block so that it's dynamically rendered. Is there a hook that will let me alter it? I can't find anything in the docs.